# how to parse one integer node

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, xmlnode, domparser

I am new to the iPhone development and I need to parse one integer node from an xml file like this:

```
 <numbers>
    <current_number>1</current_number>
 </numbers>
```

How can I retrieve "1" as an integer through my code?

thanks, and best regards

PS: I've already implemented NSXMLParserDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a DOM parser for iPhone like [GDataXMLNode](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/?r=129). It's simpler to deal with and it has an easier API.

If you really want to use NSXMLParser you'll need to keep track of the node you're on in the didStartElement and didEndElement methods. Then you'll use the foundCharacters method to get the value in between your  node. You can then just use NSString and ask for the intValue.